# Disable ipv6 in Exim4

Tags: configuration, ipv6, exim

Exim4 has an option `disable_ipv6=true`. As great in many ways as Debian/Ubuntu's split configuration files for Exim4 may be, it makes it difficult sometimes to know where to put configuration options.

Where do I add the line `disable_ipv6=true`?

Answer (score 9):

Enter a root shell:

```bsh
sudo bash
```

First you need to determine if you are using the split or the non-split configuration. Run the following:

```bsh
update-exim4.conf -v
```

Then you have to do one of the following:

1. If you are using the `non-split` configuration, edit the single-file config template directly:

```bsh
vi /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template # add "disable_ipv6 = true" in the main conf section
```

2. If you are using the `split` configuration, you need to create a new config:

```bsh
echo 'disable_ipv6 = true' > /etc/exim4/conf.d/main/90_exim4-disable_ipv6
```

Finally, you need to regenerate the Exim4 config file and restart Exim4:

```bsh
update-exim4.conf
service exim4 restart # or run "/etc/init.d/exim4 restart"
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you can check and find file config `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf`. You can add option `disable_ipv6=true` and restart exim with command `service exim4 restart`.

After you added option you can check and netstat listening on port 25 against the IPv6 address as: `netstat -tulpn | grep :25`. If port 25 have listening in IPv6 maybe you can change  `dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1 ; ::1'` --> `dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1'`.

Finally, finally, I noticed that there is a configuration template file`/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template`. Curiously, I’ve added `disable_ipv6=true` directive over there, restarted exim and maybe it started working.

I hope you will find this article useful, and save some time when you run into similar problem with exim.

Comment: `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template` step lets the black magic happen!

Answer (score 3):

If your only need is to get around Google's IPv6 reverse DNS (PTR record) [policies](https://support.google.com/mail/?p=IPv6AuthError), add the following to *main/02_exim4-config_options*.

```
dns_ipv4_lookup = *google.com : *gmail.com
```

This will effectively disable IPv6 (address lookups) to any message going to Gmail without disabling IPv6 entirely.

Answer (score 2):

```
### main/02_exim4-config_options
#################################

disable_ipv6
dns_ipv4_lookup='*'
#dns_ipv4_lookup = *gmail.com
```

I plan to get a little more fine-grained, presently I'm belt and braces sure not to need the qualifications to speak SMTP over IPv6 to Google Mail. Indeed that seems a little antethical to the ethos of the sphere.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What is this snippet? Why does it answer the question?